# c# how to join to a dictionary value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm working with a piece of code that grabs a list of contracts and adds them to a dictionary...

```
Dictionary<int, decimal> contractDictionary = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();
```

This is then populated...

sales is a variable passed into the method, there is a sales table (SalesTbl) in the database and this variable of is type SalesTbl...

```
public void UpdateSales(SalesTbl sales)
{
...
   if (!contractDictionary.ContainsKey(sales.ContractId))
   {
     contractDictionary.Add(sales.ContractId, 0);
   }
...
}
```

The code then loops through the contract dictionary to create an email body.

```
foreach (var item in contractDictionary)
{
   emailBody += string.Format("Contract {0} total sales cost: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

My problem is that this is taking the contract id and displaying it in the email along with the sales cost, the user receiving the email won't understand the contract id, I need to replace it with the contract name.  This is also available in the same method (forms has contract name, also has contractid)..

```
List<ContractForms> forms = GetFormsForSalesUpdate(update);
```

Is there a way I can easily join these two or someway to get the contract name from 'forms' to display it in place of contract id?

I hope that all made sense,

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you're using a DB just catch that id and get the name

Comment: Why don't you change the key to string and instead of adding the `sales.contractId` to be the key use the `sales.contractname`

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do using from-where-select:

```
var result = from f in forms
             from d in contractDictionary
             where f.contractid == d.Key
             select string.Format("Contract {0} total sales cost: {1}", f.contractname, d.Value);
emailbody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ContractForms> forms = GetFormsForSalesUpdate(update);
foreach (var item in contractDictionary)
{
    var form = forms.Where(f => f.ContractID == item.Key).FirstOrDefault(); 
    emailBody += string.Format("Contract {0} total sales cost: {1}", form.ContractName, item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary with key as ContractID and value as `Tuple<decimal, string>` where `string` is a name of contract. To add to `Dictionary<int, Tuple<decimal, string>>` use this: `contractDictionary.Add(sales.ContractId, new Tuple<decimal, string>(0, sales.ContractName));`. Or just use object SalesTbl as value.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `Tuple<T1, T2>` structure :

```
var contractDictionary = new DictionaryDictionary<int, Tuple<string, decimal>>();

...    
   if (!contractDictionary.ContainsKey(sales.ContractId))
   {
      contractDictionary.Add(sales.ContractId, Tuple.Create(sales.Name, 0));
   }

foreach (var item in contractDictionary.Values)
{
   emailBody += string.Format("Contract {0} total sales cost: {1}", item.Item1, item.Item2);
}
```

Or you can create your own struct that will hold data you need :

```
struct ContractData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public static ContractData Create(int id, string name, decimal value = 0)
    {
        return new ContractData() {Id = id, Name = name, Amount = value};
    }
}
```

And use it :

```
var contractDictionary = new DictionaryDictionary<int, ContractData>();

...
   if (!contractDictionary.ContainsKey(sales.ContractId))
   {
      contractDictionary.Add(sales.ContractId, ContractData.Create(sales.ContractId, sales.Name, 0));
   }


foreach (var item in contractDictionary.Values)
{
   emailBody += string.Format("Contract {0} total sales cost: {1}", item.Name, item.Amount);
}
```